# Play [2.4.2] - Add external jar to project

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

How can I add external jar file to play 2.4.2  java project? I tried to upload MyLib.jar to ./lib folder but sbt was showing errors after running activator. Any ideas?

PS. Im using IntelliJ for project.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading the JAR to the ./lib directory works for me. I am using Play 2.3.4, but according to [this page](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Anatomy), it should work the same way in 2.4. What errors are you getting?

Comment: SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Local/_drill/activator/waszka/lib/drill-jd
bc-all-1.1.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/c308030.HD00/.ivy2/cache/ch.qos.logb
ack/logback-classic/jars/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerB
inder.class]

SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorSta
ticBinder]
--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.parseMap(Ljava/ut
il/Map;)Lcom/typesafe/config/Config;
        at play.api.Configuration$.load(Configuration.scala:55)

Comment: as far I can see it is problem with my jar files. Other jars like Guava is working perfectly but for now i have to use this specific jar cause its official one and causing that problem. Any workaround?

Comment: Looks like you're having a conflict with Play classes. I don't think there's much you can do other than to resolve those conflicts.